# Do I receive more rewards by playing hard difficulty?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

When I'm playing World of Light do I receive better rewards if the difficulty is set to hard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. According to an in-game tip, you will receive better rewards in World of Light if you are playing on a harder difficulty level.

[image: World of Light tips]

Comment: What exactly are these rewards? Coins? Experience? Snacks? Something else?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs The tips unfortunately don’t clarify which rewards are increased.